# How to get output to print out next to each other?

Tags: java

Im not sure if you would need the full code to be able to help, but I've included the code that I'm having the problem with.

So I need the output of the code to print next to each other like
12    23   56   89   45   78

But it prints out each number on a different line.
How would i do that?
I've tried using \t and it doesn't help. I dont know what else to try.

```
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------");

    for ( int i = 0; i < Temperature[0].length; i++ )
    {
        System.out.println();
        columnTotal =0;
       for ( int j = 0; j < Temperature.length; j++ )
        {           
           columnTotal=columnTotal+Temperature[j][i];

        }   

       System.out.print(columnTotal/4);                                  
    }
}
```

Comment: write it all to one String (preferrably using StringBuilder) and only create and print the String  after the last for loop

Comment: `System.out.println();` prints a line aka enters the next line. If you want everthing in one line you need to delete that statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why is it printing each number on a new line?

In your `for-loop`, you use `System.out.println();` at the start of each loop. `println()` is short for `print line`, so you are essentially printing a new empty line at the start of each loop.

#### Proposed solution

To reduce the number of prints to the console, we first build what we want to print into a single `String` using `StringBuilder`. Please see the sample below:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < Temperature[0].length; i++) {
    columnTotal = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < Temperature.length; j++) {           
       columnTotal = columnTotal + Temperature[j][i];
    }   

   result.append(columnTotal / 4).append(" ");
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thanks this is a new way for me i havent learned about string builders as yet

Comment: This is the correct way to do this. Don't worry too much about the stringbuilder part right now. The important part is recognizing why they were printing out on different lines.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `System.out.println();` it is printing a new line in your loop. You should also append a space when printing `columnTotal/4`. So your code should be like:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < Temperature[0].length; i++ )
 {
   // System.out.println();
   columnTotal =0;
   for ( int j = 0; j < Temperature.length; j++ )
    {           
       columnTotal=columnTotal+Temperature[j][i];

    }   
   System.out.print((columnTotal/4) + " ");                                  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify your loop like

```
for ( int i = 0; i < Temperature[0].length; i++ )
{
   columnTotal =0;
   for ( int j = 0; j < Temperature.length; j++ )
   {           
       columnTotal=columnTotal+Temperature[j][i];

   }   

   System.out.print(columnTotal/4 + " "); 
}
```